# Scheduled import from PostgreSQL to Solr4

Tags: postgresql, solr, solr4

We have 'Article' table in PostgreSQL db with following structure (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE article
(
  id integer,
  header text,
  body text,
  isSolrized boolean
)
```

I would like to import all non-solrized rows to solr4 on a regular basis.

Is there a tool or built-in solr's mechanism to do this?

I'm going to implement my own import tool <s>with blackjack and hookers</s> and run it using cron. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think the DataImportHandler in Solr is meant for this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Comment: yes, already found it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opted for DataImportHandler.

1. Download jdbc driver for postgresql and put it in dist/ dir
2. Add modules to config file:

   ```
   <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
   <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="postgresql-\d.*\.jar" />
   ```
3. Follow instructions at [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart)
4. Remember to declare your scheme right in **scheme.xml**

Done in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a Foreign data wrapper in PostgeSQL (details and examples [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)) may be better. It can contain any logic you desire.

After implementing, it can be used in a simple trigger, or called with cron (or PostgreSQL own planner).

Such thing could be useful to other people to, if you opensource it.

Comment: thanks for advice but C is not my strong suit. Maybe I'll try to do FDW for solr for production release of our idea. Of course, open source :)